# Async.waterfall not passing callback for nested mysql queries?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, node-mysql

I have a series of nested mysql queries that I need to execute in series, as later queries rely on the result of the earlier ones - async.waterfall seems like the perfect solution. However, the second step of the waterfall is failing to append its result to my array:

```
async.waterfall([
function(callback) {
    connection.query(query, function(err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;

        var top_ten_publishers = [];
        rows.forEach(function (result) {
            var publisher_row = [result.name, result.sale_amount, result.actual_commission, result.transactions, result.post_date, result.toolbar_id, result.shop_source];

            top_ten_publishers.push(publisher_row);
        })
        callback(null, top_ten_publishers);
    })
},
function(top_ten_publishers, callback) {
    top_ten_publishers.forEach(function (publisher_row) {
        connection.query(“select  sum(sale_amount) as 'sale_amount', sum(actual_commission) as 'actual_commission', count(*) as transactions, from table where mall_name = '" + publisher_row[0] + "' and fc_post_date between '" + start_date_wow + "' and '" + end_date_wow + "' Group by name order by sum(sale_amount) desc;", function (err, rows, fields) {
            rows.forEach(function (result) {
                var wow = (publisher_row[3] - result.sale_amount) / result.sale_amount;
                publisher_row.unshift(wow);
            })
        });
    })
    callback(null, top_ten_publishers);
}
], function (err, result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

If I put a console.log inside the second step of the waterfall, I see the new values being correctly prepended to the arrays, but when the final step runs, the new values aren't in the array. Am I doing something async inside the second step that lets the callback get called before the queries are run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second function `top_ten_publishers` `forEach` makes asynchronous calls in each iteration after iterations are complete and then the function exits. Since there is no guarantee that async calls to `async.query` are also complete you end up with messed up results.

Try this modified version of `top_ten_publishers`.

```
function(top_ten_publishers, callback) {
    top_ten_publishers.forEach(function (publisher_row) {
        connection.query(“select  sum(sale_amount) as 'sale_amount', sum(actual_commission) as 'actual_commission', count(*) as transactions, from table where mall_name = '" + publisher_row[0] + "' and fc_post_date between '" + start_date_wow + "' and '" + end_date_wow + "' Group by name order by sum(sale_amount) desc;", function (err, rows, fields) {
            rows.forEach(function (result) {
                var wow = (publisher_row[3] - result.sale_amount) / result.sale_amount;
                publisher_row.unshift(wow);
            })
            callback(null, top_ten_publishers);
        });
    })
}
```

Comment: You're absolutely right - I would have sworn I tried exactly that, but it works perfectly. Thanks!